# 2 multiple select and single option list

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multi-select

I have 2 multi select element and both get options from a variable list.
If a variable selected as row variable it will not be shown in column select options. if user unselect option then variable should will shown in both list

```
$scope.variables = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

<select multiple ng-model="selectedAsRows" ng-options="v for v in variables"></select>
<select multiple ng-model="selectedAsCols" ng-options="v for v in variables"></select>
```

Comment: any plunker or fiddle to show an example of it?

Comment: So you are looking to filter the selected value of one select list from the list of options in the other select list? My first thought is something like `ng-options="v for v in variables | filter: selectedAsRows` (and similar for the other). It's not quite there, but might be a good starting point. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yqxwmakg/ I try to solve with using scope.watch if  an option selected  I try to drop from options list

Comment: Angular's filters are a much cleaner solution. Take a look at my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I understood what you want. Here is a fiddle with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/26fZb/209/

The key is to use a custom filter like this one:

```
filter: { name: '!' + selectedAsFriend.name }
```

**EDIT:**

Here is your case with multiSelect. I have created custom filters.

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(inputList, list) {
     return inputList.filter(isAlreadySelected(list));
};

  function isAlreadySelected(list){
    return function(elem){
      if (list.indexOf(elem) == -1) 
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
  }

});
```

Then to use it in the html file:

```
<select multiple ng-model="selectedAsRows" ng-options="v for v in variables | myFilter: selectedAsCols"></select>
<select multiple   ng-model="selectedAsCols" ng-options="v for v in variables | myFilter: selectedAsRows"></select>
```

Take a look at the full code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6eWZB75dAdquPD1jMmb7?p=preview

Comment: It's like you send but my select elements are multiple select and  I have 2 or 3 selectable as  row, col, layer

Comment: I have edited my answer for showing you an example adapted to you case.